# ADF Pipeline Json function only returns one element?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My issue is that json() only returns one value even if many exists.

I have a lookup activity with `select id from table` that returns a list of ids. I need a string representation that looks like the this `(1,2,3,4)`.

I have a 'Set Variable' activity  that has the following code:

```
(@{json(join(activity('Lookup1').output.value, ',')).id})
```

The Lookup.output.value return

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 4
        }
```

The Json(Join()) returns the following result:

```
{
    "name": "ids",
    "value": "(1)"
}
```

What I was expecting was the following result:

```
{
    "name": "ids",
    "value": "(1,2,3,4)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To achieve your desired result Follow below steps:**

- First you need to create an array of all Id's with Foreach and Append variable:
  Pass lookup Output to **for each activity** with expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`
  [image]
  Then inside for ech take **Append variable** and create an array variable with value `@item().Id`
  [image]
- Afte this take a set variable to join this array with delimiter and add brackets and make complete string with expression `@concat('(',join(variables('array'),','),')')`
  [image]

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: @Patrik Thanks, I was hoping to get arround a Foreach loop. Is there some way to handle it on the Source side?

Comment: As its array of Json you are getting single value in output so first we need to convert it into proper array of Id.